# Search on ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I have this problem on my search page . For example on my search page I have this data on a table

01234567
24567801

on my search if i type 01, that 2 record appear what i want is for the 
01234567 to only appear. How can i get this result?

this is the code I have on my search page:

```
dim search 
search = ""

 if tsearch <> "" then 
 if len(trim(tsearch)) <> 0 then 
    search= " AND (NUMBER_LiSt LIKE '%" & tsearch & "%')"
end if 
 end if
```

Comment: Just as alternative solution: You can use Google to search your site: 

www.google.com/?#q=24567801+site%3Ayoursite.edu

Comment: Well i can tell you why it is that way. your SQL-Query matches by LIKE and thus matches strings who contain the correct substring (01) this means any record with `01` in the NUMBER_LIST will be matched. this could also be something like `42030124`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Vogel612 is correct that the `LIKE` is looking for any instance of '01' in the NUMBER_LIST items, as you have the wildcard symbols (%) at the beginning and end of the LIKE.

If you are looking only for numbers that *start* with tsearch (eg: '01') then remove the '%' at the start of the tsearch:

```
search= " AND (NUMBER_LiSt LIKE '" & tsearch & "%')"
```

Similarly, to look for only numbers that *end* in tsearch, add the starting, and remove the trailing '%':

```
search= " AND (NUMBER_LiSt LIKE '%" & tsearch & "')"
```

Other than LIKE there are other SQL Commands for searching (like MSSQL's PATINDEX) but they are more tricky that a good LIKE.

Comment: Thanks for this sir, I have now managed to get the result i want.